# Help me make a patch for this bass stab/pluck?

Tags: sound-design, synthesizer, synthesis, bass

I'm trying to recreate this heavy and interesting bass stab/pluck that comes over the vocal at the drop of No Quarter by Zac waters.

Here's [what I'm referring too](https://soundcloud.com/zac-waters/no-quarter-original-mix#t=1:00)!

If anyone out there can tell me how make this patch or how to recreate the sound it'll be really helpful!

Answer (score 1):

Here is my attempt to recreate it in SuperCollider ([here is the code](http://sccode.org/1-4YY) and [here is audio](http://ericsluyter.com/sounds/noquarterbass.mp3))

Could use a little tweaking but I think it's pretty close.

You could definitely use any number of hardware synths or plugins to do the same thing. General method I used, create a "pluck" sound with Karplus-Strong synthesis, and combine with a triangle wave, sine wave, and sub sine (sine wave at 1/2 the frequency). I also added a "click" at the beginning to give a little more punch. Then used enveloped resonant low pass filters to give it that synthy twang, and applied a little distortion to give it some color.

Hope this is useful!